# Getting no session information while deleting app from argoCD using API

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am trying to delete the ArgoCD app from the API, but getting no session information while calling the Delete API.

```
{"error":"no session information","code":16,"message":"no session information"}
```

In the swagger, it seems pretty much easy

[image]

https://myargocd.example.com/swagger-ui#operation/ApplicationService_Delete

I already set ENV for the token

```
ARGOCD_TOKEN=my-token
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to pass the ArgoCD token as a cookies header to the delete API.

For

`<=v1.2`

> Then pass using the HTTP SetCookie header, prefixing with argocd.token:

```
$ curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/applications --cookie "argocd.token=$ARGOCD_TOKEN" 
{"metadata":{"selfLink":"/apis/argoproj.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/argocd/applications","resourceVersion":"37755"},"items":...}
```

`v1.3`

> Then pass using the HTTP Authorization header, prefixing with Bearer:

```
$ curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/applications -H "Authorization: Bearer $ARGOCD_TOKEN" 
{"metadata":{"selfLink":"/apis/argoproj.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/argocd/applications","resourceVersion":"37755"},"items":...}
```

https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer-guide/api-docs/#authorization

and finally my function is able to delete apps from the ArgoCD

```
async function deleteApp(AppName){
    let url = 'https://argocd.exampple.com/api/v1/applications/'+AppName
    let res = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            Cookie: 'argocd.token=' + process.env.ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN 
        },
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
    let body = await res.json()
    return body
}
```